# Caseinsensitive variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, apigee

I am trying to fetch value using below statement

```
var variable_2 = context.getVariable(variablefetch);
```

My requirement is to fetch this variable_1 irrespective of case.
For example if value of this variablefetch could be stored as

```
variablefetcH = typea

VAriablefetch = typea

VARIABLEFETCH = typea ....etc
```

So irrecpective of what i pass (in above case `variablefetcH,VAriablefetch,VARIABLEFETCH`) it shoule be able to fetch value `tyea`

Comment: What is `context`? How does it hold variables?

Comment: @VLAZ i am trying to fetch from Apigee API product. It holds as key value pair

Comment: That’s not what variables are for. You could use a [Proxy](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and use a case-insensitive property name.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a kind of hashmap (sometimes referred to as *hash table* or *dictionary*).

Comment: @SebastianSimon The link does not seem work (404).

Comment: @Reporter - It works for me, and I don't see an edit mark on the comment.

Comment: @Reporter The page should say something like _“The page you requested doesn't exist in German but it exists in English”_. Click that link. Wasn’t aware of this redirection behavior of MDN…

Comment: The page has an automaticly forwarding to suitable language page. For me: `.../de/...` When I changed it to `.../en/...` it works.